# Running Total Issue in DAX Power BI (need help)

Tags: dax

I am studying Power BI and I have a project in my mind. However I am having issues with the running total.

[#1 These are my working tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYeTJ.png)

The formula that you usually found in the internet for running total is something like this.

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Transaction'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Transaction'),
        'Transaction'[Date] <= MAX('Transaction'[Date])
    )
)
```

However I wanted to have a slicer so that when I click a specific account, it will give me the whole the running total for that account, and when I select all, will display the running total for all accounts.

[#2 Sample visual here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTHYo.png)

As you can see in the 2nd image, the running total looks fine. However this is not reacting whenever I select a specific account. So I did some research and updated my measure formula to this:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Transaction'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Transaction'),
        'Transaction'[Date] <= MAX('Transaction'[Date]) &&
        'Transaction'[Account] IN VALUES('Transaction'[Account])
    )
)
```

The update makes the table react to the slicer and it gives me the correct number. However the problem now is when I select all. It gives me the result in image 3. The last record should have a value of 9. I am not really sure why. What I only know is this is happening whenever the primary account has transaction on a specific date, while the secondary account has no corresponding record for that date (in this case, the 26th). If both have transactions on 26th, the measure calculation is fine. Can someone please help me understand what is happening?

[#3 Issue with running total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUxm4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have this problem: you are using a wrong table in the formula for dates. You need to use date table instead, like this:

```
Cumulative Amount    =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Transaction'[Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date Table' ),
        'Date Table'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date Table'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Comment: It worked. I am new to Power BI, can you explain to me what is the difference? Why is it an error when using the other table? I mean shouldn't it be the same since the two tables have a relationship between the dates column?

Comment: In your formula, you are using ALL function on the Transactions table. This function removes all filters that affect the table, including slicers; as a result, slicer does not work. In my formula, only filters from the date table are removed, leaving other Transaction table  filters unaffected. More generally, you should always use star schema for your data model, and base your slicers and filters on dimensions only. But that's another topic.

Comment: You can read more here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/